# Chart in Javascript with non-numeric values

Tags: javascript, charts

I need to make a chart, with Months in the X axis, and LETTER values in the Y axis (e.g. The maximun value is "A" and the Minimum value is "G", like a clasification), but the demos and libraries on the web only show examples Name/Numericvalue...

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? We aren't going to just do your work for you.

Comment: how are you making the charts? what libraries (if any) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

How about you create a mapping from character-values to numeric values.

```
var mapping = {
   'A': 1,
   'B': 2,
   //...
   'G': 7
};
```

Everytime you want a numeric value, you just make a lookup:

```
var value = mapping['A'];
```